# How to change background color of datePicker?

Tags: css

I have two quick questions regarding the DatePicker:

1. How can I change the background color of the datePicker in CSS? For example, I want to change the green color to blue?

[datepicker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy1GC.png)

(for information, I can't use JS)

2. How to add a "calendar" icon to the right of the input?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <input
    type="text"
    #dp="bsDatepicker"
    bsDatepicker
    [(bsValue)]="myDateValue"
  />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

::ng-deep.bs-datepicker {
  height: 350px;
}

.custom-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1081;
  top: 390px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
}
```

Here is a representation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51062003-urfipa?file=app%2Fapp.component.css)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the styling of the datepicker you do so by

```css
::ng-deep.bs-datepicker .bs-datepicker-head{
  background-color: blue !important;
}

::ng-deep.bs-datepicker .selected{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

for the icon you need to add it on the html and than style it .

```html
<div class="inputContainer" >
    <input
      type="text"
      #dp="bsDatepicker"
      bsDatepicker
      [(bsValue)]="myDateValue"
    />
    <span class="inputIcon">
      <img
        src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/7168/calendar.svg"
      >
    </span>
  </div>
```

```css
::ng-deep.bs-datepicker .bs-datepicker-head{
  background-color: blue !important;
}

::ng-deep.bs-datepicker .selected{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Here is the demo https://stackoverflow-51062003-6khnoa.stackblitz.io